# Is there a Spanish origin to the Cebuano word 'porbida'?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, filipinas

Looking at *[porbida](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/porbida#Cebuano)*, one may think it's from *por vida*; the Wiktionary entry assumes the same thing. I couldn't find a discussion that would suggest why *porbida* is used similar to the English expression *for crying out loud*.

Is there an old Spanish word or idiom similar to *porbida* or *por vida*, that could be the origin of this Philippine word?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are asking for the etymology of a Cebuano word, that would render this question off-topic in this site, so I can only hint a possible origin. The expression *por vida* was already used in the 16th century in the Spanish language. It was as a way of speaking used to persuade or force the concession of what is intended.

Example:

> Por vida tuya que hagas esto.

It was also used as an assertion and as an oath (swear something on someone's life):

> Daban los Jones tanto crédito, y autoridad à la berza, que juraban por vida de ella, como si fuera algun Dios.

You could also use *por vida mía* to swear on your own's life or express your determination to do something or make someone do something:

> Por vida mia, que te disculpes agora.

This last sentence, written in 1642, can easily be translated as something like *you'd better apologise now, goddammit*, making the expression *por vida mía* a way of expressing anger, much like the Cebuano word *porbida*, which [is used](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/porbida) "to express anger, irritation, disappointment, annoyance, contempt, etc.". According to [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cebuano_language), the language was heavily influenced by the Spanish language during the period of colonialism from 1565 to 1898. So it is quite plausible that the Cebuano expression *porbida* comes from the Spanish language given the similarities.

Answer (score 1):

According to [*Diccionario Ingles-Español-Tagalog*](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/docs/books/gutenberg/2/0/7/3/20738/20738-h/20738-h.htm), Sofronio G. Calderón  (1915), the word has the same meaning as the temptingly similar Spanish phrase "por vida mía":

> Alife, *adv.* [aláif]
> Por vida mia.
> *Porbida (sumpâ).*

The following volume affirms this is indeed its origin:

> Muchas de las exclamaciones que se usan en la vida diaria de los tagalos y los cebuanos proceden del espanol, como, por ejemplo: ... *porbida!* (esp. "por vida de"), exclamación de disgusto;
>
> - [*La lengua española en Filipinas: historia, situación actual, el chabacano, antología de textos*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xq_Lr-47DVUC&pg=PA413&lpg=PA413&dq=%22porbida%22+%22por+vida%22) (p.413)

Note also the archaic word [*porvida*](https://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=porvida) (same meaning) in Spanish.

Comment: Again, not sure why I'm being downvoted for this... Looks like someone is going through my posts and downvoting one obscure thing a day...